# How to test if a point is on a spline

Tags: algorithm, cairo, spline, gtk2hs

I'm writing a drawing application. I want to draw a 2d spline and then test if the user has clicked on it. I know that finding the distance from an arbitrary point to a spline is complicated, but I just want to know if I'm within a couple of pixels. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

If its relevant, I'm using Cairo via the Gtk2Hs library in Haskell.

Comment: Tesselate the spline and see which point im the tesselation is closest to the user's click.

Comment: @n.m. By "tesslate", do you mean approximating it by splitting it up into lots of little line segments? I did wonder about that, but I thought I'd see if there is a better way.

Comment: Yes that's tesselation. That's how the spline is drawn on the screen, and it happens fast enough.

Comment: Usually you'd test whether the point is within the convex hull of the control points, then refine by hulls of segments until the size of the hull is less than the tolerance you require.

Comment: What does `2d spline` mean in `Cairo via the Gtk2Hs`? There are dozens of diffferent spline kinds. Perhaps algebraic solution exists (complexity depends on spline description). However, in most cases subdivision in straight segments is the simplest approach and provides reasonably fast way.

Comment: @MBo Cairo is a widely used graphics library, part of GTK, which includes curved lines drawn using splines. Gtk2Hs is a Haskell wrapper around GTK.

Comment: @Paul Johnson OK, I've read Cairo docs and saw that `spline` is Bezier curve. There is algebraic approach requiring solving of polynomial equation of 5-th degree (not very simple/robust task). So subdivision is still good alternative.

Comment: BTW, I've used one more approximate way: check vertical and horizontal distances to curve (it requires solving cubic polynomial, quite simple).

Comment: How about just using cairo to tesselate the curve? You get a cairo context from somewhere, cairo_curve_to() your curve, set your desired line width and check with cairo_in_stroke().